# python eyed3 eyed3.id3.tag.CommentsAccessor object at 0x7fbb2316d890

Tags: python, python-2.7, eyed3

When I try and read the comments from any MP3 file using eyed3 I get given the following error:

```
eyed3.id3.tag.CommentsAccessor object at 0x7fbb2316d890
```

Doe's anyone know how to fix this?

```
track = eyed3.load(name)
print track.tag.comments
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```py
track = eyed3.load(audio_filename)
print track.tag.comments[0].text
```

```bsh
$ pip freeze | grep eyeD3
eyeD3==0.7.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read comments using following code:

```
track = eyed3.load(name)
print track.comments[0].text
```